# Creating reduced Dataset from existing Torchvision Dataset

Tags: python, dataset, torchvision

We all know the common MNIST dataset, included in the `torchvision.datasets` package. Imagine that I want to create a reduced version of this dataset containing only *1* and *0* to classify only this two numbers instead all 10 values.

I've seen that custom datasets can be created within a class that inherits the desired Dataset, so `__getitem__`, which returns the item at the given index. So I've done this:

```py
class MNIST01(MNIST):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image, label = super().__getitem__(idx)
        if label.item() <= 1:
            return image, label
        else:
            return None
```

The problem is that it seems that I can't return a None value as it's required to be "contain tensors, numbers, dicts or lists; found class 'NoneType'".

Is there a simple way to get a reduced version of this Dataset easily in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to deal with the NoneType Problem. Keeping the function defined in the question.

```py
class MNIST01(MNIST):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        features, target = super(MNIST01, self).__getitem__(idx)
        if target.item() <= 1:
            return features, target
```

We now need to define a custom [collate function](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-use-collate-fn/27181) `collate_fn` for our dataloader, which process the list of samples to form a batch. In this function, we can apply a filter to deal with `None`values and ignore them.

```py
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import default_collate

def filter_collate(batch):
    batch = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, batch))
    return default_collate(batch)
```

Then we just need to pass this function to the `DataLoader`:

```py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, collate_fn=filter_collate, **kwargs)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, collate_fn=filter_collate, **kwargs)
```

**Version 2**

Much more easy than the first one, avoiding some problems when accessing data. Just filter directly the `train_data` and `train_label` attributes (and corresponding for test set) from the instanciation of `MNIST` class.

```py
train_dataset.train_data = train_dataset.train_data[train_dataset.train_labels <= 1]
train_dataset.train_labels = train_dataset.train_labels[train_dataset.train_labels <= 1]
```